# How do I add multiple values to the list?

Tags: python, list

```py
counts: List[int] = ?
```

I will get an int from the user's input through the console, and depending on that number I will need to add 0's to the list above. E.g if user inputs 10, I need to add 10 zeroes to the list.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you don't get an `int`, you get `str` from `input()`(Python 3+) , You can then use `.extend` or `+=`:

```py
counts: list[int] = []
n = int(input())
counts.extend([0] * n)
# counts += [0] * n
```